# VS 2010 - TFS: DLL locked

Tags: visual-studio, tfvc

when I try to compile an old Visual Studio 2010 ASP.NET Web Forms solution,
I got this error for a DLL locked:

---

### Microsoft Visual Studio

### The item $/DEVELOP/GestioneProfiliSAP/Website/Bin/ESDToolKit.dll is locked for check-out by IT400018 in workspace MILL3482.

### OK

---

### Microsoft Visual Studio

### The command you are attempting cannot be completed because the file 'ESDToolKit.dll' that must be modified cannot be changed. If the file is under source control, you may want to check it out; if the file is read-only on disk, you may want to change its attributes.

### OK

At the moment, I don't have access to TFS server, but I can compile the solution
for ESDToolkit and get his DLL.

Is it possible solve this problem?

Comment: Remove the `bin` folder from source control and your local computer and add it to `.tfignore`. Do the same for `obj` folders and other folders containing build outputs.

Comment: Vs2010 doesn't support local workspaces and `tfignore` files. In this case it also depends on how that file got added to the project. Is it a direct binary dependency? Is it from a NuGet?

Comment: It's a binary dependency.